# jquery fadeIn() from opacity: 0.1 - possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to fadeIn() a div that starts of on `opacity: 0.1` or (`filter: alpha(opacity = 10)` in ie).

I know i can do `.animate({css....` with an `if(supports opacity)` but i'm looking for a quick and easy cross browser solution, and i imagine jquery already has one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
.animate({ opacity: 1 });
```

There no need to check [`$.support.opacity`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), it'll use the alpha filter version if needed, jQuery normalizes this internally.  To be clear, this supports all browsers, including IE.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/7HwGn/).

*Edit:*  re-reading your question it seems these styles may be in the stylesheet, not set by [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), in which case just add a `zoom: 1` for IE to fade correctly, [you can view a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/7HwGn/1/).  You can see how the guts of it work [here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L52).

Comment: bloody ie, with the zoom:1 fix i've got it fading brilliant, but when it comes to rest on alpha 100 it suddenly looks awful! Must be something to do with IE's alpha and the transparent png image im using. oh well, i think this can be an embellishment ie users can go without (for now)! thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

```
time = 1000; // time in ms to fade from 0.1 to 1
$("#id").fadeTo(0, 0.1).fadeTo(time, 1)
```

Comment: FYI.. `fadeTo` with duration of 0 is the same as calling `css('opacity', ...)` directly. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the opacity using `css` then begin the `fadeIn`

E.g.

```
yourElement.css('opacity', .1).fadeIn();
```